# Append span to prev a

Tags: jquery

I have a little problem.

```
<li>
    <a></a>
    <span>Description 1</span>
</li>

<li>
    <a></a>
    <span>Description 2</span>
</li>
```

I want to append the span to the prev a without using a class or the content.
Can you help me?

I tried something like this, but then I copy the span into each `<a>` tag:

```
$('li span').appendTo($('li span').prev());
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you elaborate, I think what you mean is you want to add, Desc 1 into Desc 2? is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking to accomplish?

```
$('li span').each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo( $(this).prev() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rRsdz/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way,

```
​$("li a").append(function(){
   return $(this).next(); 
});​​​​​
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://jsfiddle.net/JH8pg/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
​$('li').each(function(i, li) {
   $(li).find('a').append($(li).find('span'));
});​​​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RUt3/). I added some colors and behaviors to show you it worked without looking at the dom